# Floating items in the background like Pinterest

Tags: pinterest, floating

I need to create a function similar to the one that is on Pinterest or better on http://www.sumally.com - sliding elements in the background. Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Thanks,

Aleksandar

Answer (score 0):

[image]Each div or "rows" on that site has something called -webkit-transition and -webkit-transformations applied. Look those up and you should be on your way. But there is more that goes into it because it looks like they are using smarty, like twig to load the images, so there really is not just a "function" to do all of that.